# Wizarding Public Servants?

Tags: harry-potter

We often see fires, murders, and magical maladies in the Wizarding World.

We're aware of the Magical Law Enforcement office, but what about firefighters, disease control, Armed Forces, etc.?

Does the Wizarding world employ other public servants?

Comment: Aurors are most likely the "standing army". Why would they need firefighters though? Natural fires would be put down by Aquamenti or something similar, black magic fires would have to be put out by counter curses so a firefighter wouldn't help either

Comment: @Oak A single Augamenti spell wouldn't be enough to put out a forest fire...Curse breakers (for magical fires) should be employed. IT's not whether or not there's firefighters, but public servants in the same manner (actually working rather than behind a desk).

Comment: Keep in mind that the concept of (for example) public safety forces - police and fire fighters employed and paid by government - is as I recall less than a couple of hundred years old. It's quite possible that the Wizarding world hasn't "caught up" to Muggles in that sense.

Comment: I think most of the jobs at the Ministry (and there are quite a few detailed in the books) count, as well as the healers of various kinds at St Mungo's.

Comment: @Anoplexian In fact, fires are apparently put out using the Extinguishing Spell, not Aguamenti: see GoF, "We’ll be on hand if it gets nasty, Extinguishing Spells at the ready" (Charles Weasley).

Comment: @A.Darwin That's exactly the point, and thanks for the quote to back it up!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there are firefighters. If there is a forest fire, a wizard could protect themselves with Augamenti, or even try to manipulate the flames as Dumbledore can do.

Alternatively, if there was a forest fire, a wizard would just leave and let whoever would normally deal with it, deal with it. Unless it was a magical fire, I doubt it would be dealt with by the ministry.

> "But what does a Ministry of Magic do?"
>
> "Well, their main job is to keep it from the Muggles that there's
>   still witches an' wizards up an' down the country."
>
> "Why?"
>
> "Why? Blimey, Harry, everyone'd be wantin' magic solutions to their
>   problems. Nah, we're best left alone." - *Philosophers Stone*

Things like disease control or armed services would get assigned to one of the departments in the ministry, depending on the complexity of the situation. Wizards also have magical means of remedying muggle illnesses, and if there is a disease, there's more likely a reason behind it like a magical creature, i.e. the Nundu who can kill entire African villages in one breath (which could be seen as a disease outbreak to muggles).

> The Nundu is a rare beast, found in East Africa. Its appearance is similar to a leopard though a Nundu is far larger. A Nundu’s breath is deadly and is known to eliminate whole villages at a time.  - *Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them*

Alternatively, wizards can develop new potions/solutions for diseases or poisons, like the Wolfsbane potion to lessen the effects of lycanthropy, the Pepper-up potion to cure colds and warm up the user, or even a Bezoar which can cure most poisons. It could be seen as a public service depending on whether you feel this serves the public!

*(Full list can be found here - http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_potions)*

By looking at the Ministry of Magic department list, we can see a variety of public servant jobs that could arise from each one of them:

> Level 1: Minister of Magic and Support Staff
>
> Level 2: Department of Magical Law Enforcement, Improper Use of Magic
>   Office, Auror Headquarters Wizengamot, Administration Services
>
> Level 3: Department of Magical Accidents and Catastrophes, Accidental
>   Magic Reversal Squad, Obliviator Headquarters, Muggle-Worthy Excuses
>   Committee
>
> Level 4: Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical
>   Creatures Beast, Being and Spirit Divisions, Pest Advisory Bureau
>
> Level 5: Department of International Magical Cooperation, International
>   Magical Trading Standards Body, International Magical Office of Law,
>   International Confederation of Wizards, British Seats
>
> Level 6: Department of Magical Transportation, Floo Network Authority,
>   Broom Regulatory Control, Portkey Office, Apparition Test Center
>
> Level 7: Department of Magical Games and Sports, British and Irish
>   Quidditch League Headquarters, Official Gobstones Club, Ludicrous
>   Patents Office
>
> Atrium
>
> Department of Mysteries
>
> Courtrooms

Additionally you have healers at St Mungoes who are essentially Doctors and Nurses and anyone that will essentially "Heal" a problem.

For other incurable diseases that require control, Wizards generally have an isolation policy and avoid any with illnesses as demonstrated by Ron with Spattergroit, and when Molly Weasley was wondering why the wolf in Order of the Phoenix wasn't in a private ward.

> "So we’re going to put out the story that I’m seriously ill with
>   spattergroit, which is why I can’t go back to school. If anyone comes
>   calling to investigate, Mum or Dad can show them the ghoul in my bed,
>   covered in pustules. Spattergroit’s really contagious, so they’re not
>   going to want to go near him. It won’t matter that he can’t say
>   anything, either, because apparently you can’t once the fungus has
>   spread to your uvula." - *Deathly Hallows*

and

> "A werewolf?" whispered Mrs. Weasley, looking alarmed. "Is he safe in a public ward? Shouldn’t he be in a private room?" *Order of the Phoenix*

Comment: " if there was a forest fire, a wizard would just leave and let whoever would normally deal with it, deal with it" What about the Forbidden Forest? If it is Unplottable, Muggle firefighters wouldn't even find the place. Even if it was plottable and reachable by Muggles, it would still be a dangerous place(giants, centaurs,...). As an aside, Dumbledore has a strong affinity with fire, and he can make something burn forever (Gubraithian fire). We are lucky he is not an arsonist!

Comment: @A. Darwin - I don't think Scottish forests have to worry too much about forest fires ;-)